# How to reset particular field [React-admin]

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I would like to reset particular field (element) of SimpleForm from react-admin v4

At the moment the form have 3 related field like:

- A
- B
- C

When you select A the select B is enabling and when B the same if for the C.
The happy flow works very well.

Currently I'm using the `FormDataConsumer` so fields are dependent.

The problem is when user decide change element A or B. Then the form is not reloading again and the source is still the same.

So for example:

User selected A, `field_a = X`, then selected B, `field_b = Y`, then selected C, `field_c = Z`

Then the A has been updated so the result is the following:

- field B is clear (only from UI perspective) because the `formData.field_a` is still set
- field C is still set.

Do you have any ideas how to set the data base on `onChange` action?

I tried to use the `refs`, `react-hook-form` and `register`.

Is it any way to reset one field or many fields form form?

The form based on `Input Components` and `<SimpleForm>` provided by `React-admin`

Answer (score 2):

The `useForm() / useFormContext()` hooks return a method: `resetField("fieldName")`

https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/resetfield

Comment: But I'm using the `<Form>`  and `Input Components` so I suppose that for that the `useForm` is not work

Comment: useFormContext() returns similar methods

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution.
The problem was with the context.
The `useFormContext` can be used but inside the `<Form>`
So I use `resetField` inside my component (custom autocomplete) and It work.